# Core Data relationship to same entity

Tags: ios, core-data

I have been using archiving and I am switching to Core Data--however, I don't know how to implement a certain entity that I want to add to the database.

Here is how I would have written the header file not using Core Data...

```
@interface SELCase : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property (nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *caseKey;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL individual;
@property (nonatomic) float indivAmount;
@property (nonatomic) SELCase *indivType;

@end
```

Data that would be loaded every time would be the name, caseKey, and individual. If individual was YES then that would be the end of it, but if it wasn't an individual then indivAmount and indivType would be loaded.

**The problem is that I need a relationship to another SELCase and I have no idea how to do that. Any help?**

Comment: ctrl+drag from `SELCase` entity to itself (in the coredata graph editor) to create a parent/child relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a relationship that points to the same entity.

Here's an example:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * goalName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * goalPicture;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * indexOrder;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * wordPicture;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *item;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Goal *parent;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *subGoals;
@property (nonatomic, retain) User *user;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *video;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *stats;
@end

@interface Goal (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addItemObject:(Item *)value;
- (void)removeItemObject:(Item *)value;
- (void)addItem:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeItem:(NSSet *)values;

- (void)addSubGoalsObject:(Goal *)value;
- (void)removeSubGoalsObject:(Goal *)value;
- (void)addSubGoals:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeSubGoals:(NSSet *)values;

- (void)addVideoObject:(Video *)value;
- (void)removeVideoObject:(Video *)value;
- (void)addVideo:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeVideo:(NSSet *)values;

- (void)addStatsObject:(Stats *)value;
- (void)removeStatsObject:(Stats *)value;
- (void)addStats:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeStats:(NSSet *)values;
```

In this case, the subGoals is a set consisting of the same type of entity.

In your model you'll just make a relationship (one/one, one/many, whatever) that points to the same entity.

Comment: What about the inverse? Set it to the same relationship? Relationship: indivType -- Destination: SELCase -- Inverse: indivType?

Comment: The inverse is going to point to SELCase.  In my example, Goal *parent points to the Goal object that is the "parent" of the current item.  When you create one of these entities, you'll place a pointer to the parent SELCase object in it.  This way, you can traverse the objects up or down the list efficiently.